# Postgresql 9.6 Parallel execution from foreign table

Tags: oracle, postgresql, parallel-processing, oracle-fdw

I upgraded my postgresql from 9.5 to 9.6 in order to use the parallel execution to improve my performance. However, I didnt succeed to use it. In my main database almost all my selects look like : 
`select * from foreign_table` 
The foreign table is a foreign table that is located on an oracle database.
Some of the tables are big 10G+ and 1,000,000+ records so parallel query should help me alot in this case of select.

The parameters that i configured :

```
min_parallel_relation_size = 200MB
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2 
max_worker_processes = 8
```

When I try to use explain analyze select * from a big table that her size is 1.5G and has 5,000,000 records I see only foreign scan :

```
 Foreign Scan on customer_prod  (cost=10000.00..20000.00 rows=1000 
width=2438) (actual time=6.337..231408.085 rows=5770616 loops
=1)
  Oracle query: ......
 Planning time: 2.827 ms
 Execution time: 232198.137 ms
```

*I also tried select * from foreign_table where 1=1 but still same result.

On the other hand the next code worked :

```
   postgres=# CREATE TABLE people_mariel_test (id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, age int NOT NULL);
   CREATE TABLE
   postgres=# INSERT INTO people_mariel_test  SELECT id, (random()*100)::integer AS age FROM generate_series(1,10000000) AS id;
   INSERT 0 10000000
   postgres=# explain analyze select * from people_mariel_test where age=6;
                                                            QUERY PLAN

   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ------------------------------------------------
   ----------
   Gather  (cost=1000.00..123777.76 rows=50000 width=8) (actual        time=0.239..771.801 rows=99409 loops=1)
      Workers Planned: 1
      Workers Launched: 1
      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on people_mariel_test  (cost=0.00..117777.76 rows=29412 width=8) (actual time=0.045..748.213 rows=49704
    loops=2)
     Filter: (age = 6)
     Rows Removed by Filter: 4950296
    Planning time: 0.261 ms
    Execution time: 785.924 ms
   (8 rows)
```

Any idea how can I continue?

Comment: add `ora_fdw` tag and hope to get Laurenz attention. But I very much doubt that postgres parallel execution setting will not affect the extension

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/fdw-callbacks.html#FDW-CALLBACKS-PARALLEL):

> A ForeignScan node can, optionally, support parallel execution. A
>   parallel ForeignScan will be executed in multiple processes and should
>   return each row only once across all cooperating processes. To do
>   this, processes can coordinate through fixed size chunks of dynamic
>   shared memory. This shared memory is not guaranteed to be mapped at
>   the same address in every process, so pointers may not be used. The
>   following callbacks are all optional in general, **but required if
>   parallel execution is to be supported**.

I have searched source code for Oracle FDW by Laurenz Albe and it does not implement `IsForeignScanParallelSafe` and thus cannot use parallel execution.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz. Shit, Is there a way I can improve performance if that is the case ?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing with that data. Can it be processed individually (in partitions)? Can you make actual partitions on Oracle server? You can try some [alternate parallel extensions](https://pgxn.org/dist/pmpp/doc/pmpp.html) or make your own.

Comment: Hi, I cant make partitions of those tables in oracle server. When you wrote "make your own" you meant to write an extension ? In general, I`m only selecting * from 70 tables in oracle server into local postgresql tables.

Comment: Not necessarily extension, more like a mechanism/system for parallel execution, like a thread manager of sorts. We have that kind of thing where I work but it is too complicated for StackOverflow answer and I wouldn't be able to share it anyway. If you can't make partitions on Oracle server then you will also have to figure out how to efficiently split that data - that alone would be lengthy read as there are multitude of approaches to this issue and all of them have their cons and pros (sadly I can't find that article now).